# I have closed the IIS Admin, but the 80 port still be occupied by the System process

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

I have closed the IIS Admin：

[image]

---

[image]

but the 80 port still occupy by System process：

[image]

---

My system is Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: The port 80 can be occupied by many applications (PID 4 means HTTP.sys the driver), and IIS is just one of them. If your goal is to shut down all such, run `net stop http`.

Answer (score 1):

To stop all the sites on the server, you can stop the "world wide web publishing service". If the requirement is to stop the site at port 80, it should be stopped from the admin tool (the second screenshot) and reset IIS using command iisreset from an elevated command prompt. There will be an outage for the other sites as well when the IIS restarts.

Comment: can you provide the detail operation, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just stop the WWW Publisher:

```
C:\> sc stop W3SVC
```

IIS services an listeners are documented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/236166/using-net-stop-and-net-start-commands-to-force-iis-services-to-re-read).